# Multiple calls to std::cout make subprocess hang

Tags: c++, windows, subprocess, wxwidgets

I'll copy here part of my previous question to describe the problem:

> I wrote an application in C++ that has two parts - the frontend and
>   the backend. These two communicate using IPC layer provided by
>   wxWidgets. In the backend I use some legacy functions for image data
>   manipulation. One of these functions hangs or falls into some infinite
>   loop sometimes (I can observe that 0% of the process resources are
>   used by the process after some point), but this happens only if I ran
>   the backend as a subprocess of the frontend. Otherwise (when I run it
>   manually) it works just fine.

It turns out that printing too many lines with `std::cout` was causing that, but I'd like to understand why. Could it be that wxWidgets utilizes some buffer for storing application output and printing was simply overflowing it? Or this is rather native issue of Windows? Or maybe it could be related to `std::cout` implementation? <s>I'm pretty sure I'm not able to reproduce this with `printf`</s> It seems that I was wrong - `printf` also seems to trigger that issue

Comment: You're pretty sure or you're 100% sure (you actually tested it)?

Comment: I won't lie: this sounds unlikely.

Comment: it would be better if you copied the parts of your code that reproduce the observed issue.

Comment: Are you calling std::cout and when you debug and step over that line it hangs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stdout buffer is of a finite size. Something must be reading what you are writing into the buffer, whether this is a file, a console window or another process. If you write faster than the reader is able to cope with then the buffer will eventually fill up and block any further writes until the reader has read some data.